# How to get value from header component? React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a button on my header right that open up a drop down component. The component allow user to make some selection and apply it after the user hit the 'apply' button.

After the apply button pressed, it should be able to pass the value back to the 'main screen' component. How do I pass the value back to the 'main screen' ?

This is my interface , if you're wondering what I'm trying to do. 
[image]

*edit* 
I tried to pass in the useState function to the header component to update the state after the apply button pressed by passing it using the setParam from react navigation props. Is there any other better way to get the value ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like:

```
props.navigation('Home', { state: SOME_VALUE });
```

Here is the react navigation doc to do this.
[React navigation passing params to previous screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen)

Or you can use redux store.